# SFML Project microsoft visual express 2010 to 2012 compatibility issue

Tags: c++, linker, compatibility, sfml

This program and it runs fine in microsoft visual 2010 express, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it running in microsoft visual 2012 express. Could someone please tell me why?

Here is the error and warning output: 
[image]

Here is the source code for the program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <sfml/audio.hpp>
#include <sfml/system.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif // M_PI

// ...

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    sf::RenderWindow Window;

    Window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3");

    Window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);



    //sf::Music music;
    //if (!music.openFromFile("thinking.ogg"))
    //  return -1;

    //music.play();

    //sf::Font MyFont;

    //MyFont.loadFromFile("times.ttf");
    //

    //sf::Text text("Happy Valentines Day!", MyFont);
    //text.setCharacterSize(30);
    //text.setPosition(200, 340);
    //text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    //text.setColor(sf::Color::White);
    //  
    //sf::Text textt("You are so special,", MyFont);
    //textt.setCharacterSize(30);
    //textt.setPosition(200, 380);
    //textt.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    //textt.setColor(sf::Color::White);
    //
    //sf::Text texttt("to me!", MyFont);
    //texttt.setCharacterSize(30);
    //texttt.setPosition(200, 420);
    //texttt.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    //texttt.setColor(sf::Color::White);        

    //sf::Text texty("I", MyFont);
    //texty.setCharacterSize(30);
    //texty.setPosition(395, 270);
    //texty.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    //texty.setColor(sf::Color::White);


    sf::Time time = sf::seconds(.01);

    sf::Time heartone = sf::seconds(1);
    sf::Time hearttwo = sf::seconds(2);
    sf::Time heartthree= sf::seconds(3);
    sf::Time heartfour = sf::seconds(4);

    sf::Time winclrone = sf::seconds(6);

    sf::Time letterc = sf::seconds(6.5);
        sf::Time lettera = sf::seconds(7);
            sf::Time letterr = sf::seconds(7.5);
                sf::Time letterrr = sf::seconds(8);
                    sf::Time letteri = sf::seconds(8.5);
                        sf::Time lettere = sf::seconds(9);



    sf::Clock clock;

// first two hearts
    int x0 = 800 / 2; // Coordinates of the center of the heart
    int y0 = 600 / 2;

    int size = 400; // Size of the heart

    int r = size / 3;


    int xx0 = 800 / 2; // Coordinates of the center of the heart
    int yy0 = 600 / 2;

    int sizee = 400; // Size of the heart

    int rr = sizee / 5;

// hearts 2 - 4
    int xxx0 = 800 / 2; // Coordinates of the center of the heart
    int yyy0 = 600 / 2;

    int sizeee = 400; // Size of the heart

    int rrr = sizeee / 10;


    int xxxx0 = 800 / 2; // Coordinates of the center of the heart
    int yyyy0 = 600 / 2;

    int sizeeee = 400; // Size of the heart

    int rrrr = sizeeee / 15;

//// hearts 4 - 6
//    int xxx0 = 800 / 2; // Coordinates of the center of the heart
//    int yyy0 = 600 / 2;
//
//    int sizeee = 400; // Size of the heart
//
//  int rrr = sizeee / 10;
//
//
//    int xxxx0 = 800 / 2; // Coordinates of the center of the heart
//    int yyyy0 = 600 / 2;
//
//    int sizeeee = 400; // Size of the heart
//
//  int rrrr = sizeeee / 7;
//  


// first two hearts
    // Radius of the curves

    int total_curve_vertex_count = 40; // Maximum number of vertices per curve
    int total_vertex_count = 80; // Total number of vertices: 30 + 10 + 10 + 30


    int total_curve_vertex_countt = 40; // Maximum number of vertices per curve
    int total_vertex_countt = 80; // Total number of vertices: 30 + 10 + 10 + 30

// hearts 2 - 4
    // Radius of the curves

    int total_curve_vertex_counttt = 40; // Maximum number of vertices per curve
    int total_vertex_counttt = 80; // Total number of vertices: 30 + 10 + 10 + 30


    int total_curve_vertex_countttt = 40; // Maximum number of vertices per curve
    int total_vertex_countttt = 80; // Total number of vertices: 30 + 10 + 10 + 30


// first two hearts

    struct CurveInfo // Store information for each of the four square curves
    {
        int vertex_count;
        double t0; // Angle origin
        double s; // Angle sign: +1 or -1
        int cx, cy; // (Relative) coordinates of the center of the curve
    }
    curve_infos[4] =
    {
        // Upper-left
        { 3 * total_curve_vertex_count / 4,        0.0, -1.0, -r, -r},
        // Lower-left
        {     total_curve_vertex_count / 4, 1.5 * M_PI,  1.0, -r,  r},
        // Lower-right
        {     total_curve_vertex_count / 4,       M_PI,  1.0,  r,  r},
        // Upper-right
        { 3 * total_curve_vertex_count / 4, 0.5 * M_PI, -1.0,  r, -r},
    };

        struct CurveInfoo // Store information for each of the four square curves
    {
        int vertex_countt;
        double tt0; // Angle origin
        double ss; // Angle sign: +1 or -1
        int cxx, cyy; // (Relative) coordinates of the center of the curve
    }
    curve_infoss[4] =
    {
        // Upper-left
        { 3 * total_curve_vertex_countt / 4,        0.0, -1.0, -rr, -rr},
        // Lower-left
        {     total_curve_vertex_countt / 4, 1.5 * M_PI,  1.0, -rr,  rr},
        // Lower-right
        {     total_curve_vertex_countt / 4,       M_PI,  1.0,  rr,  rr},
        // Upper-right
        { 3 * total_curve_vertex_countt / 4, 0.5 * M_PI, -1.0,  rr, -rr},
    };

// hearts 2 - 4


    struct CurveInfooo // Store information for each of the four square curves
    {
        int vertex_counttt;
        double ttt0; // Angle origin
        double sss; // Angle sign: +1 or -1
        int cxxx, cyyy; // (Relative) coordinates of the center of the curve
    }

    curve_infosss[4] =
    {
        // Upper-left
        { 3 * total_curve_vertex_counttt / 4,        0.0, -1.0, -rrr, -rrr},
        // Lower-left
        {     total_curve_vertex_counttt / 4, 1.5 * M_PI,  1.0, -rrr,  rrr},
        // Lower-right
        {     total_curve_vertex_counttt / 4,       M_PI,  1.0,  rrr,  rrr},
        // Upper-right
        { 3 * total_curve_vertex_counttt / 4, 0.5 * M_PI, -1.0,  rrr, -rrr},
    };

        struct CurveInfoooo // Store information for each of the four square curves
    {
        int vertex_countttt;
        double tttt0; // Angle origin
        double ssss; // Angle sign: +1 or -1
        int cxxxx, cyyyy; // (Relative) coordinates of the center of the curve
    }

    curve_infossss[4] =
    {
        // Upper-left
        { 3 * total_curve_vertex_countttt / 4,        0.0, -1.0, -rrrr, -rrrr},
        // Lower-left
        {     total_curve_vertex_countttt / 4, 1.5 * M_PI,  1.0, -rrrr,  rrrr},
        // Lower-right
        {     total_curve_vertex_countttt / 4,       M_PI,  1.0,  rrrr,  rrrr},
        // Upper-right
        { 3 * total_curve_vertex_countttt / 4, 0.5 * M_PI, -1.0,  rrrr, -rrrr},
    };

// first two hearts

    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> vertices(total_vertex_count);
    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> verticess(total_vertex_countt);

    int vertex_index = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        CurveInfo& curve_info = curve_infos[i];
        int vertex_count = curve_info.vertex_count;
        double t0 = curve_info.t0;
        double s = curve_info.s;
        int cx = x0 + curve_info.cx;
        int cy = y0 + curve_info.cy;

        for(int j = 0; j < vertex_count; j++)
        {
            double dt = s * 2.0 * M_PI * j / (total_curve_vertex_count - 1);
            int x = cx + r * cos(t0 + dt);
            int y = cy + r * sin(t0 + dt);
            vertices[vertex_index++] = sf::Vector2f(x, y);
        }
    }


    int vertex_indexx = 0;

    for(int ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++)
    {
        CurveInfoo& curve_infoo = curve_infoss[ii];
        int vertex_countt = curve_infoo.vertex_countt;
        double tt0 = curve_infoo.tt0;
        double ss = curve_infoo.ss;
        int cxx = xx0 + curve_infoo.cxx;
        int cyy = yy0 + curve_infoo.cyy;

        for(int jj = 0; jj < vertex_countt; jj++)
        {
            double dtt = ss * 2.0 * M_PI * jj / (total_curve_vertex_count - 1);
            int x = cxx + rr * cos(tt0 + dtt);
            int y = cyy + rr * sin(tt0 + dtt);
            verticess[vertex_indexx++] = sf::Vector2f(x, y);
        }
    }

// hearts 2 - 4

    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> verticesss(total_vertex_counttt);
    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> verticessss(total_vertex_countttt);

    int vertex_indexxx = 0;

    for(int iii = 0; iii < 4; iii++)
    {
        CurveInfooo& curve_infooo = curve_infosss[iii];
        int vertex_counttt = curve_infooo.vertex_counttt;
        double ttt0 = curve_infooo.ttt0;
        double sss = curve_infooo.sss;
        int cxxx = xxx0 + curve_infooo.cxxx;
        int cyyy = yyy0 + curve_infooo.cyyy;

        for(int jjj = 0; jjj < vertex_counttt; jjj++)
        {
            double dttt = sss * 2.0 * M_PI * jjj / (total_curve_vertex_counttt - 1);
            int x = cxxx + rrr * cos(ttt0 + dttt);
            int y = cyyy + rrr * sin(ttt0 + dttt);
            verticesss[vertex_indexxx++] = sf::Vector2f(x, y);
        }
    }


    int vertex_indexxxx = 0;

    for(int iiii = 0; iiii < 4; iiii++)
    {
        CurveInfoooo& curve_infoooo = curve_infossss[iiii];
        int vertex_countttt = curve_infoooo.vertex_countttt;
        double tttt0 = curve_infoooo.tttt0;
        double ssss = curve_infoooo.ssss;
        int cxxxx = xxxx0 + curve_infoooo.cxxxx;
        int cyyyy = yyyy0 + curve_infoooo.cyyyy;

        for(int jjjj = 0; jjjj < vertex_countttt; jjjj++)
        {
            double dtttt = ssss * 2.0 * M_PI * jjjj / (total_curve_vertex_countttt - 1);
            int x = cxxxx + rrrr * cos(tttt0 + dtttt);
            int y = cyyyy + rrrr * sin(tttt0 + dtttt);
            verticessss[vertex_indexxxx++] = sf::Vector2f(x, y);
        }
    }

// first two hearts

    // Generate the vertices of the lines primitives
    int total_line_count = total_vertex_count - 1;
    // Don't duplicate the first and last vertices
    int line_vertex_count = 2 * total_vertex_count - 2;


    // Generate the vertices of the lines primitives
    int total_line_countt = total_vertex_countt - 1;
    // Don't duplicate the first and last vertices
    int line_vertex_countt = 2 * total_vertex_countt - 2;


// hearts 2 - 4

    // Generate the vertices of the lines primitives
    int total_line_counttt = total_vertex_counttt - 1;
    // Don't duplicate the first and last vertices
    int line_vertex_counttt = 2 * total_vertex_counttt - 2;


    // Generate the vertices of the lines primitives
    int total_line_countttt = total_vertex_countttt - 1;
    // Don't duplicate the first and last vertices
    int line_vertex_countttt = 2 * total_vertex_countttt - 2;



    while(Window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event Event;
        while(Window.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            switch(Event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                Window.close();
                break;
            }


        }


//name

// Letter C

                sf::VertexArray vArrayC(sf::Lines, 16);
                vArrayC[0].position = sf::Vector2f(52, 300);
                vArrayC[1].position = sf::Vector2f(52, 84);
                vArrayC[2].position = sf::Vector2f(52, 84);
                vArrayC[3].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 84);
                vArrayC[4].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 84);
                vArrayC[5].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 100);
                vArrayC[6].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 100);
                vArrayC[7].position = sf::Vector2f(69, 100);
                vArrayC[8].position = sf::Vector2f(69, 100);
                vArrayC[9].position = sf::Vector2f(69, 284);
                vArrayC[10].position = sf::Vector2f(69, 284);
                vArrayC[11].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 284);
                vArrayC[12].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 284);
                vArrayC[13].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 300);
                vArrayC[14].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 300);
                vArrayC[15].position = sf::Vector2f(52, 300);
                //vArrayC[16].position = sf::Vector2f(200, 100);
                //vArrayC[17].position = sf::Vector2f(200, 100);
                for(int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
                {
                    int red = rand() % 255;
                    int green = rand() % 255;
                    int blue = rand() % 255;

                    vArrayC[k].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
                }

//Letter A

                sf::VertexArray vArrayA(sf::Lines, 22);
                vArrayA[0].position = sf::Vector2f(190, 300);
                vArrayA[1].position = sf::Vector2f(240, 84);
                vArrayA[2].position = sf::Vector2f(210, 300);
                vArrayA[3].position = sf::Vector2f(260, 100);
                vArrayA[4].position = sf::Vector2f(190, 300);
                vArrayA[5].position = sf::Vector2f(210, 300);
                vArrayA[6].position = sf::Vector2f(300, 84);
                vArrayA[7].position = sf::Vector2f(350, 300);
                vArrayA[8].position = sf::Vector2f(300, 84);
                vArrayA[9].position = sf::Vector2f(240, 84);
                vArrayA[10].position = sf::Vector2f(330, 300);
                vArrayA[11].position = sf::Vector2f(280, 100);
                vArrayA[12].position = sf::Vector2f(280, 100);
                vArrayA[13].position = sf::Vector2f(260, 100);
                vArrayA[14].position = sf::Vector2f(350, 300);
                vArrayA[15].position = sf::Vector2f(330, 300);

                vArrayA[16].position = sf::Vector2f(235, 200);
                vArrayA[17].position = sf::Vector2f(305, 200);
                vArrayA[18].position = sf::Vector2f(240, 180);
                vArrayA[19].position = sf::Vector2f(300, 180);
                vArrayA[20].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 100);
                vArrayA[21].position = sf::Vector2f(170, 100);
                for(int k = 0; k < 22; k++)
                {
                    int red = rand() % 255;
                    int green = rand() % 255;
                    int blue = rand() % 255;

                    vArrayA[k].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
                }


// Letter R

                sf::VertexArray vArrayR(sf::Lines, 24);
                vArrayR[0].position = sf::Vector2f(370, 300);
                vArrayR[1].position = sf::Vector2f(390, 300);
                vArrayR[2].position = sf::Vector2f(370, 300);
                vArrayR[3].position = sf::Vector2f(370, 84);
                vArrayR[4].position = sf::Vector2f(390, 300);
                vArrayR[5].position = sf::Vector2f(390, 100);
                vArrayR[6].position = sf::Vector2f(370, 84);
                vArrayR[7].position = sf::Vector2f(470, 84);
                vArrayR[8].position = sf::Vector2f(390, 100);
                vArrayR[9].position = sf::Vector2f(450, 100);
                vArrayR[10].position = sf::Vector2f(450, 170);
                vArrayR[11].position = sf::Vector2f(390, 170);
                vArrayR[12].position = sf::Vector2f(470, 190);
                vArrayR[13].position = sf::Vector2f(410, 190);
                vArrayR[14].position = sf::Vector2f(470, 84);
                vArrayR[15].position = sf::Vector2f(470, 190);
                vArrayR[16].position = sf::Vector2f(450, 100);
                vArrayR[17].position = sf::Vector2f(450, 170);
                vArrayR[18].position = sf::Vector2f(410, 190);
                vArrayR[19].position = sf::Vector2f(470, 300);
                vArrayR[20].position = sf::Vector2f(450, 300);
                vArrayR[21].position = sf::Vector2f(390, 190);
                vArrayR[22].position = sf::Vector2f(470, 300);
                vArrayR[23].position = sf::Vector2f(450, 300);

                for(int k = 0; k < 24; k++)
                {
                    int red = rand() % 255;
                    int green = rand() % 255;
                    int blue = rand() % 255;

                    vArrayR[k].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
                }

//Letter r#2


                sf::VertexArray vArrayRR(sf::Lines, 24);
                vArrayRR[0].position = sf::Vector2f(490, 300);
                vArrayRR[1].position = sf::Vector2f(510, 300);
                vArrayRR[2].position = sf::Vector2f(490, 300);
                vArrayRR[3].position = sf::Vector2f(490, 84);
                vArrayRR[4].position = sf::Vector2f(510, 300);
                vArrayRR[5].position = sf::Vector2f(510, 100);
                vArrayRR[6].position = sf::Vector2f(490, 84);
                vArrayRR[7].position = sf::Vector2f(590, 84);
                vArrayRR[8].position = sf::Vector2f(510, 100);
                vArrayRR[9].position = sf::Vector2f(570, 100);
                vArrayRR[10].position = sf::Vector2f(570, 170);
                vArrayRR[11].position = sf::Vector2f(510, 170);
                vArrayRR[12].position = sf::Vector2f(590, 190);
                vArrayRR[13].position = sf::Vector2f(530, 190);
                vArrayRR[14].position = sf::Vector2f(590, 84);
                vArrayRR[15].position = sf::Vector2f(590, 190);
                vArrayRR[16].position = sf::Vector2f(570, 100);
                vArrayRR[17].position = sf::Vector2f(570, 170);
                vArrayRR[18].position = sf::Vector2f(530, 190);
                vArrayRR[19].position = sf::Vector2f(590, 300);
                vArrayRR[20].position = sf::Vector2f(570, 300);
                vArrayRR[21].position = sf::Vector2f(510, 190);
                vArrayRR[22].position = sf::Vector2f(590, 300);
                vArrayRR[23].position = sf::Vector2f(570, 300);

                for(int k = 0; k < 24; k++)
                {
                    int red = rand() % 255;
                    int green = rand() % 255;
                    int blue = rand() % 255;

                    vArrayRR[k].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
                }
//Letter I

                sf::VertexArray vArrayI(sf::Lines, 24);
                vArrayI[0].position = sf::Vector2f(610, 300);
                vArrayI[1].position = sf::Vector2f(630, 300);
                vArrayI[2].position = sf::Vector2f(610, 300);
                vArrayI[3].position = sf::Vector2f(610, 84);
                vArrayI[4].position = sf::Vector2f(630, 300);
                vArrayI[5].position = sf::Vector2f(630, 84);
                vArrayI[6].position = sf::Vector2f(610, 84);
                vArrayI[7].position = sf::Vector2f(630, 84);

                for(int k = 0; k < 24; k++)
                {
                    int red = rand() % 255;
                    int green = rand() % 255;
                    int blue = rand() % 255;

                    vArrayI[k].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
                }
//Letter E


                sf::VertexArray vArrayE(sf::Lines, 24);
                vArrayE[0].position = sf::Vector2f(650, 300);
                vArrayE[1].position = sf::Vector2f(770, 300);
                vArrayE[2].position = sf::Vector2f(650, 84);
                vArrayE[3].position = sf::Vector2f(770, 84);
                vArrayE[4].position = sf::Vector2f(650, 300);
                vArrayE[5].position = sf::Vector2f(650, 84);
                vArrayE[6].position = sf::Vector2f(770, 84);
                vArrayE[7].position = sf::Vector2f(770, 105);
                vArrayE[8].position = sf::Vector2f(770, 300);
                vArrayE[9].position = sf::Vector2f(770, 281);
                vArrayE[10].position = sf::Vector2f(770, 105);
                vArrayE[11].position = sf::Vector2f(670, 105);
                vArrayE[12].position = sf::Vector2f(770, 281);
                vArrayE[13].position = sf::Vector2f(670, 281);
                vArrayE[14].position = sf::Vector2f(670, 281);
                vArrayE[15].position = sf::Vector2f(670, 200);
                vArrayE[16].position = sf::Vector2f(670, 105);
                vArrayE[17].position = sf::Vector2f(670, 180);
                vArrayE[18].position = sf::Vector2f(670, 200);
                vArrayE[19].position = sf::Vector2f(740, 200);
                vArrayE[20].position = sf::Vector2f(670, 180);
                vArrayE[21].position = sf::Vector2f(740, 180);
                vArrayE[22].position = sf::Vector2f(740, 200);
                vArrayE[23].position = sf::Vector2f(740, 180);
                for(int k = 0; k < 24; k++)
                {
                    int red = rand() % 255;
                    int green = rand() % 255;
                    int blue = rand() % 255;

                    vArrayE[k].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
                }


                sf::VertexArray vArrayXX(sf::Lines, 6);
                vArrayXX[0].position = sf::Vector2f(395, 300);
                vArrayXX[1].position = sf::Vector2f(405, 300);
                vArrayXX[2].position = sf::Vector2f(395, 280);
                vArrayXX[3].position = sf::Vector2f(405, 280);
                vArrayXX[4].position = sf::Vector2f(400, 280);
                vArrayXX[5].position = sf::Vector2f(400, 300);


                for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
                {
                    int red = rand() % 255;
                    int green = rand() % 255;
                    int blue = rand() % 255;

                    vArrayXX[k].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
                }


// first two hearts
    sf::VertexArray vArray(sf::Lines, line_vertex_count);
    sf::VertexArray vArrayy(sf::Lines, line_vertex_countt);

    int line_index = 0;
    vertex_index = 0;

    int line_indexx = 0;
    vertex_indexx = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < total_line_count; k++)
    {
        vArray[line_index++].position = vertices[vertex_index++];
        vArray[line_index++].position = vertices[vertex_index];
    }


    for(int k = 0; k < line_vertex_count; k++)
    {
        int red = rand() % 255;
        int green = rand() % 133;
        int blue = rand() % 255;

        vArray[k].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
    }

    for(int kk = 0; kk < total_line_countt; kk++)
    {
        vArrayy[line_indexx++].position = verticess[vertex_indexx++];
        vArrayy[line_indexx++].position = verticess[vertex_indexx];
    }

    for(int kk = 0; kk < line_vertex_countt; kk++)
    {
        int red = rand() % 255;
        int green = rand() % 255;
        int blue = rand() % 255;

        vArrayy[kk].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
    }


// hearts 2-4
    sf::VertexArray vArrayyy(sf::Lines, line_vertex_counttt);
    sf::VertexArray vArrayyyy(sf::Lines, line_vertex_countttt);

    int line_indexxx = 0;
    vertex_indexxx = 0;

    int line_indexxxx = 0;
    vertex_indexxxx = 0;

    for(int kkk = 0; kkk < total_line_counttt; kkk++)
    {
        vArrayyy[line_indexxx++].position = verticesss[vertex_indexxx++];
        vArrayyy[line_indexxx++].position = verticesss[vertex_indexxx];
    }


    for(int kkk = 0; kkk < line_vertex_counttt; kkk++)
    {
        int red = rand() % 255;
        int green = rand() % 133;
        int blue = rand() % 255;

        vArrayyy[kkk].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
    }

    for(int kkkk = 0; kkkk < total_line_countttt; kkkk++)
    {
        vArrayyyy[line_indexxxx++].position = verticessss[vertex_indexxxx++];
        vArrayyyy[line_indexxxx++].position = verticessss[vertex_indexxxx];
    }

    for(int kkkk = 0; kkkk < line_vertex_countttt; kkkk++)
    {
        int red = rand() % 255;
        int green = rand() % 255;
        int blue = rand() % 255;

        vArrayyyy[kkkk].color = sf::Color(red, green, blue);
    }



                 time = clock.getElapsedTime();

                 //std::cout << time.asSeconds() << std::endl;


                 Window.draw(vArrayXX);

                if(time >= heartone)
                     Window.draw(vArrayyyy);
                if(time >= hearttwo)
                     Window.draw(vArrayyy);
                if(time >= heartthree)
                     Window.draw(vArrayy);
                if(time >= heartfour)
                     Window.draw(vArray);

                if(time >= winclrone)
                     Window.clear();

                if(time >= letterc)
                    Window.draw(vArrayC);
                if(time >= lettera) 
                    Window.draw(vArrayA);
                if(time >= letterr) 
                    Window.draw(vArrayR);
                if(time >= letterrr)    
                    Window.draw(vArrayRR);
                if(time >= letteri) 
                    Window.draw(vArrayI);
                if(time >= lettere) 
                    Window.draw(vArrayE);

                if(time >= sf::seconds(10))
                    std::cout << "Happy Valentines Day! You are so Special to me!" << std::endl;

                 Window.display();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Regarding your code, you should use a for loop instead of blocks of text

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-build SFML with Visual Studio 2012. It's trying to link in parts of the standard library that were either renamed or don't exist in the 2012 runtime.

You also need to do a clean before you build, after upgrading to a different version of Visual Studio. The 'mismatch detected' errors mean that it's trying to link an object file built with an older compiler; recompiling those object files will fix it, and doing a clean forces everything to be recompiled.